# How to make "No Duplicates" column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, unique, unique-constraint

I have a simple table in my SQL Server database. This table contains two columns: `ID int, Name nvarchar(50)`. The `ID` column is the primary key for my table.

I want the "`Name`" column to be "`(No Duplicates)`", like in Microsoft Access, But this column isn't the primary column. How could I do this?

Comment: Please don't roll back the changes to your tags - This question is not about Microsoft Access, but rather unique constraints on SQL Server.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827(SQL.80).aspx) for that column:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Name UNIQUE (Name)
```

---

To add it through SQL Management Studio UI:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Expand the *Tables* folder of the database where you wish to create the constraint.
3. Right-click the table where you wish to add the constraint and click *Design*.
4. In Table Designer, click on *Indexes/Keys*.
5. Click *Add*.
6. Choose *Unique Key* in the Type drop-down list.

To handle a situation where a unique constraint violation occurs, see for [error 2601](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql2000/html/trblsql/tr_reslsyserr_1_2fu9.htm).

Comment: the link is for Sql Server 2000 and the instruction for SSMS are not applicable to the latest version as far as I can see.

Comment: +1 for the solution.. I have done the same and I am not able to insert the duplicate value. But primary key values are loosing for my each try... mean if my PK is 1 and I am trying to insert a duplicated value twice. The next correct update will be of PK 4. How can I avoid it ?

Comment: I prefer this answer to the GUI solution I posted because it's really much simpler and faster but I posted anyway for those that have a strong GUI preference.

Comment: Confirmed working EXCEPT select "Modify" not "Design" in Step 3 as that option doesnt exist.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be done another way with the SSMS GUI if you prefer:

1. Right click "Indexes" under your table in the SSMS Solution Explorer and click "New Index..." (I know you are looking to create a contstraint, not an index, but this is exactly what the `ADD CONSTRAINT` SQL script does.

[image]

2. Give new index a name (e.g. "UQ_MyUniqueColumn"), check "Unique", and click "Add..."

[image]

3. Check your column in the next window

[image]

4. Click OK in both windows

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.rampant-books.com/t_super_sql_127_unique_constraint_clustered.htm).